# Translating T-SQL INNER JOIN statement into DAX

Tags: t-sql, dax, daxstudio

I have the following code in T-SQL, where it's calculated distinct [ClientID] of [C-Services] table, based on certain conditions, and with joining [C_Episode] table on a multiple fields:

```
SELECT 
   cs.[ProgramName] AS [Program]
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT cs.[ClientID]) AS [# Clients Served]

FROM 
  [C_Services] cs
  INNER JOIN [C_Episodes] epi ON (

        (epi.[ProgramID] = cs.[ProgramID])
    AND (epi.[ClientID] = cs.[ClientID])
    AND (epi.[AdmissionDate] <= cs.[ServiceMonth])
    AND (epi.[DischargeDate] >= cs.[ServiceMonth])
                                        )
WHERE
       (cs.[ClientID] > 0)
   AND (cs.[IsNoShow] = 0) 
   AND (cs.[IsCancellation] = 0)
   AND (cs.[IsNonClaimable] = 0)

GROUP BY
     cs.[ProgramName]
```

Also, I also have DAX Measure associated with the above code, but without INNER JOIN [C-Episodes] table:

```
VAR countClients =
    CALCULATE (
       DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'C_Services'[ClientID] ),
               FILTER (
                       'C_Services',
                              [ClientID] > 0
                           && [Is Non-Claimable] = FALSE ()
                           && [Is No-show] = FALSE ()
                           && [Is Cancellation] = FALSE ()
                      )
                 )
                 RETURN
                      countClients
```

My question is -
How do I have to modify DAX measure in order to add INNER JOIN [C_Episodes] table (joined on three conditions stated in T-SQL code)?

I was trying to add, for the 1st JOIN ON ProgramID column

```
NATURALINNERJOIN('C_Services'[ProgramID], 'C_Episodes'[ProgramID])
```

But it given an error - "Grouping needed", and after I was trying to change my Calculate to Summarize or to Summarizecolumns - it still given an errors.

Comment: What does the inner join to `[C_Episodes]` do? Does it filter the data? Because it has no absolutely no bearing on anything in the select clause or the `WHERE` filter

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, it filters certain episodes. (data)
I NEED to inner join that table, but don't know how to write it in DAX !

Comment: Use the filter function to exclude rows

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  But - In order to exclude rows I need that JOIN .
I need to match  C_Episodes to C_Services  by  ProgramIDs, ClientIDs and Dates (accordng to my T_SQL conditions).     How do I do it using filter?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you right now, just keep in mind that all that join is doing is _filtering_, so `FILTER` is the likely path to take.

Comment: But I definitely take your point - DAX is a very different language and it's very difficult to find solutions to things that seem as trivial as a join.

Comment: Also that join could be rewritten as `EXISTS`, and that may bring it close to something that is DAXable

Comment: Do you actually get different numbers out of this query if you don't join to `[C_Episodes]`? You say above "it filters certain episodes" but you don't use any data from episodes in your select or where

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes after JOIN I get lower numbers and that's been tested earlier and that's what's needed

Comment: Can you please provide sample data for [C_Services] and [C_Episodes] with either a TSQL DDL or by providing two sample tables here.

Comment: Did the answer below help? I tested it and it appears to be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL can be rewritten like this:

```
SELECT 
   cs.[ProgramName] AS [Program]
  ,COUNT(
       DISTINCT 
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (
       SELECT * 
       FROM [C_Episodes] epi
       WHERE (epi.[ProgramID] = cs.[ProgramID])
       AND (epi.[ClientID] = cs.[ClientID])
       AND (epi.[AdmissionDate] <= cs.[ServiceMonth])
       AND (epi.[DischargeDate] >= cs.[ServiceMonth])
  ) THEN cs.[ClientID] ELSE NULL END
) AS [# Clients Served]

FROM 
  [C_Services] cs
WHERE
       (cs.[ClientID] > 0)
   AND (cs.[IsNoShow] = 0) 
   AND (cs.[IsCancellation] = 0)
   AND (cs.[IsNonClaimable] = 0)

GROUP BY
     cs.[ProgramName]
```

and this is more in line with DAX's measure-centric view of the world.

If we

- focus on the `[# Clients Served]` measure
- assume that the ProgramName group by will be handled by the visualisation
- Assume your existing filter can be reused

Then you should be able to use this for a **column** calculation in the `C_Episodes` table:

```
ClientMatched = 
IF(
    ISEMPTY(
        FILTER(
        'C_Episodes', 
        'C_Episodes'[ProgramID] = 'C_Services'[ProgramID] &&
        'C_Episodes'[ClientID] = 'C_Services'[ClientID] &&
        'C_Episodes'[AdmissionDate] <= 'C_Services'[ServiceMonth] &&
        'C_Episodes'[DischargeDate] >= 'C_Services'[ServiceMonth]
        )
    ),
    BLANK(),
    [ClientID]
)
```

If there is a matching record in C_Episodes, the column will contain the ClientID, if not it will be blank.

This can be also extended with your other filter.

Now you can use this measure:

```
DistinctClientCount = DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(Services[ClientMatched])
```

I'm not sure how efficient this is but try it out

For completeness, these are DAX expressions to create the tables I used to test:

## C_Services

```
C_Services = UNION(
    ROW("ProgramId", 1, "ClientId", 1,"ServiceMonth",DATE(2021,2,1)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 1, "ClientId", 1,"ServiceMonth",DATE(2021,3,1)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 1, "ClientId", 1,"ServiceMonth",DATE(2021,4,1)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 1, "ClientId", 2,"ServiceMonth",DATE(2021,2,1)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 1, "ClientId", 2,"ServiceMonth",DATE(2021,3,1)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 1, "ClientId", 2,"ServiceMonth",DATE(2021,4,1)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 2, "ClientId", 1,"ServiceMonth",DATE(2021,2,1)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 2, "ClientId", 1,"ServiceMonth",DATE(2021,3,1)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 2, "ClientId", 1,"ServiceMonth",DATE(2021,4,1))
)
```

## C_Episodes

```
C_Episodes = UNION(
    ROW("ProgramId", 1, "ClientId", 1,"AdmissionDate",DATE(2021,1,15),"DischargeDate",DATE(2021,2,15)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 1, "ClientId", 2,"AdmissionDate",DATE(2022,5,15),"DischargeDate",DATE(2022,6,15)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 4, "ClientId", 1,"AdmissionDate",DATE(2021,2,15),"DischargeDate",DATE(2021,3,15)),
    ROW("ProgramId", 1, "ClientId", 2,"AdmissionDate",DATE(2021,2,15),"DischargeDate",DATE(2021,3,15))    
)
```

Comment: @NickMcDemand  Thank you I am out of PC access  But I'll try on wed, 7/07 and will let you know

Comment: Thank you for these variations
Unfortunately the problem appears not in what I've described above - but in the raw data sources - needs sql and some 3rd party communications to resolve.  In a process now!

I'll leave this post because TONS of valuable info for the future
Thank you again